# Providing different shared items for each activity with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

How would I provide a completely different set of data to each service in with a UIActivityViewController?

For instance:

- MESSAGE an image of a hat, and the text "This is a hat"
- FACEBOOK a url - http://www.google.com , and the text "Find a hat here"
- EMAIL an image of a cat, and the url lolcats.com
- CUSTOM SERVICE an image

Comment: I don't believe you can, unless you can somehow 'listen' to see which UIActivity button the user pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide different data for different activities by creating a class that adopts `UIActivityItemSource` protocol and implements the method:

```
-(id)activityViewController:itemForActivityType:
```

Then pass the object of your custom class to your `UIActivityViewController` in activityItems array with a call `-(id)initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities:`

From documentation of this method:

> ... Instead of actual data objects, the objects in this array can be objects that adopt the UIActivityItemSource protocol, such as UIActivityItemProvider objects. ...

Here is a tutorial about how to do that: https://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/objective-c-custom-uiactivityviewcontroller-icons-and-text/

Comment: Tutorial missing.  Does anyone know of another one?